# Facebook Test User shows no email address

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the official [facebook-sdk for Python](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk). According to the docs I should see the email in profile.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
```

And I do see it when I use an access token from my own user.

But when I use the access token from a test user, as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool) how to create them for the app, I don't get the email address.

```
{u'first_name': u'Mark', u'last_name': u'Baoberg', u'middle_name': u'Amhdjdddhada', u'name': u'Mark Amhdjdddhada Baoberg', u'locale': u'en_GB', u'gender': u'male', u'verified': False, u'updated_time': u'2014-09-20T11:04:50+0000', u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxx', u'timezone': 0, u'id': u'yyyy'}
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: did you ask for the permission?

Comment: You might be right. How do I set permissions for test users?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Test User like every other User. Just use the login icon in the Test Users overview to login with the Test User and open your App - i assume you asked for the email in the scope parameter (because it works with your User), so just do the same login process with your Test User and it should be fine.

Comment: why the downvote? please comment a reason, so i can improve my question if you believe that something is wrong.